# Compare to_date(CurrentDate) with timestamp

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle, timestamp

I just want to compare my current date with the timestamp field only date not time but it does not compare with it because the query becomes something like this. How can i do that kindly help

Query:

```
SELECT com.PHONE_NUMBER
FROM communication com
WHERE com.COMMUNICATION_DATE = TO_DATE('23-11-15', 'dd-MM-yy')
```

DB table field value:

```
02-NOV-15 18.56.00.000000000
```

Function:

```
    public static String getCurrentDate() throws ParseException
    {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy");
        Date date = new Date();

        return dateFormat.format(date);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to_timestamp function?

Comment: I just want to compare the date not time

Comment: Can it help you? https://community.oracle.com/thread/2381171. You can use  TRUNC simply.

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam Using **TRUNC** would not use any index on the date column. So, better use date  range condition as I have shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>**NOTE:** Actually it's almost impossible to match actual date with milliseconds with a stored date.</s>

**UPDATE:**

> I just want to compare the date not time

---

Then, get an instance of a `Calendar` to get today's date, set fields to zero (hour, minute, etc...) and compare with a `SimpleDateFormat` extracting only date:

```
public static boolean isEqualDate(String toCompare) throws Exception {
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
    Date toCompareDate = df.parse(toCompare);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    return toCompareDate.equals(calendar.getTime());
}
```

**EXAMPLE OF EXECUTION:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String date = "23-NOV-15 18.56.00.000000000";
    System.out.println(isEqualDate(date));
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
true
```

Comment: Wait.. isn't it SQL question related to date arithmetic? Or am I missing something?

Comment: wait, you can see also a java method converting string to date? or you are ingnoring the part of the question you are not interested in?

Comment: I am just asking you genuinely whether it depends on the SQL and Java both? As it would leave our answers incomplete. No offense!

Comment: @LalitKumarB you can solve programmatic questions in many ways, here you can find the solution with native sql or processing this results with Java, no incomplete answers, just 2 ways of doing the same thing...

Comment: Alright, thanks. I was curious to know as I am clueless about Java.

Answer (score 0):

> WHERE com.COMMUNICATION_DATE = TO_DATE('23-11-15', 'dd-MM-yy')

**Equality operator** would fail to fetch for the rows which has **time portion**.

You could use **TRUNC** on the date column, however, that would suppress any **index** usage on the date column.

Correct and efficient way is to use a **date range condition** such that it would use any regular **index** on the **date column**.

```
WHERE com.COMMUNICATION_DATE >= TO_DATE('23-11-15', 'dd-MM-yy')
AND   com.COMMUNICATION_DATE <  TO_DATE('23-11-15', 'dd-MM-yy') +1
```

Also, when you are dealing with only date element without any time portion, then use **ANSI Date literal** which uses a fixed format `'YYYY-MM-DD'` therefore it is **NLS independent**.

```
WHERE com.COMMUNICATION_DATE >= DATE '2015-11-23'
AND   com.COMMUNICATION_DATE <  DATE '2015-11-23' +1
```

A simple demo:

```
SQL> SELECT *
  2  FROM dual
  3  WHERE SYSTIMESTAMP >= DATE '2015-11-23'
  4  AND   SYSTIMESTAMP <  DATE '2015-11-23' +1;

D
-
X
```

Comment: It may arise error: SQL Error: ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam Why? It's impossible. I added a demo, see the answer.

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam: with the SQL in this answer, it's impossible for that error to show up.

Comment: `'2015-11-23' +1` includes '2015-11-24 00:00:00'. We don't know if this is what the OP wants. Better use `TRUNC(com.COMMUNICATION_DATE) = DATE '2015-11-23'` or `BETWEEN TO_DATE('23-11-15', 'dd-MM-RR') 
AND TO_DATE('23-11-15 23:59:59', 'dd-MM-RR hh24:mi:ss')`: Also use `RR` instead of `YY` if you use only 2 digits - or even better use four digits, i.e. `YYYY`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Yes, I shouldn't have used BETWEEN here. I meant >= and <.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Here the important part is the date range condition, RR part is not the highlight of the question. And it is not what I am asking OP to use, I would rather use YYYY, and it comes pretty good with ANSI date literal. And I would not use TRUNC, I would only go with the range as shown.